# PopupWindow углы сделать прозрачными

Tags: java, android

Проблема в том что всплывающем окне на верху есть тень в углах, возможно ли это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: dialog.setBackgroundDrawable(null) попробуй

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой минимальный код для воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.